# multiplying and rounding numbers using sed

Tags: sed, decimal, rounding, multiplication

I have the following question for the scripting experts: how to multiply the number i.e. 12.34567 by 100 and then round it to two decimals using sed?

Thanks in advance!
Irek

Comment: echo "12.34567 100" | sed "s,.*,dc -e '&*p',e;s,\(.*[.]..\).*,\1,"

Comment: Using sed really is the way to go for this, if you like doing things the 'difficult/challenging' way for fun you should check out the Code Golf Stack site.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the source for an [RPN calculator](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/dc.sed) written in sed.  That should get you started.